# I have a question with mute system discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, mute

I have a problem with my mute system. If I send `+mute @member` it doesn't give a role.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === "+mute") {
      if (!message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
        return message.reply({content: `You need permissions to use command`})
        const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('<986283559092359228>');
        if (!mutedRole)
          return message.reply('There is no Muted role on this server');
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        member.roles.add(role); 
        message.channel.send(member + 'has Been Muted');
      } else {
        message.channel.send("You didn't mention the user to mute!")
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You define your mute role as `mutedRole`, but when you give member a role - you use `role`, which doesn't exist, so solution is simple, change `member.roles.add(role);` to `member.roles.add(mutedRole);`

Comment: I did it, but everything is the same :(

Comment: @Almis do you get any errors in console? If so - please add it to your question

Comment: no there is nothing

Comment: @Almis also I noticed you write your role ID as `<986283559092359228>`, but `<>` shouldn't be there, so it may cause the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write only the role ID when defining muteRole, so change this

```js
const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('<986283559092359228>');
```

To this

```js
const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('986283559092359228');
```

Then use the same name `mutedRole` in `role.add()` and use `try/catch` because the bot cannot give a role that is higher than its highest role, so try:

```js
try {
    member.roles.add(mutedRole);
  } catch (err) {
           console.log(err)
           message.channel.send({content: `Role is higher than my highest role!`})
           }
```

Just to add, you can directly do

```js
message.channel.send({content: `${member} has Been Muted`});
```

You also need to check if the user has the `mutedRole` already or not